# Expressing a single sentence with multiple lines in predicate logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I'm currently working on the following task

```
Use the predicate Like(x, y) which is read as “x likes y”. 
Use the predicate Subject(x) as well, which is read as “x is a school subject”. 
Equal = and not equal ≠ are also to be used. 
Use x and y as variable names. 
Express the following sentences a) – f)  in predicate logic:
```

, and here are my answers.

```
(a) Stina likes all subjects. 
  ∀x (Subject(x)  -> Like(Stina, x) )

(b) There is a subject that Gustav likes.  
  ∃x (Subject(x) -> Like(Gustav, x)) 

(c) Hubert likes something that Svante and Gustav like. 
  ∀x (Subject(x) ∧ Like(Svante, x) ∧ Like(Gustav, x) -> Like(Hubert, x))

(d) Rut doesn’t like herself but she likes everyone who likes her.
  ∀x (¬Like(Rut, Rut) ∧ Like(x, Rut) -> Like(Rut, x))

(e) Gustav likes someone who likes math.
  ∀x∃y (Subject(y) ∧ y = math ∧ Like(x, y) -> Like(Gustav, x))

(f) Hubert likes all subjects except for math and logic, and Gustav likes math, Rut likes logic and Svante likes Rut and statistics.
  ∀x (Subject(x) ∧ x ≠ math ∧ x ≠ logic -> Like(Hubert, x))
  ∀x (Subject(x) ∧ x = math -> Like(Gustav, x))
  ∀x (Subject(x) ∧ x = math -> Like(Rut, x))
  ∀x ((Subject(x) ∧ x = statistic) V (x = Rut) -> Like(Svante, x))
```

In my answer for (f), I ended up writing multiple lines in predicate logic, but is this legitimate? If it's not, how do I sum them up into a single line? 
Also, is there anything wrong with how I solve the problems in (a)-(e) as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a): correct

---

(b): correct

---

(c): Hubert only likes *something* that Svante and Gustav like, not *everything*, and it's not said that this something is a subject (in (d), it's about persons), so

```
∃x (Like(Svante, x) ∧ Like(Gustav, x) ∧ Like(Hubert,x))
```

(One could think about a rather hardly accessible reading where "something" is indeed to be read as "everything", as in "If Gustav and Svante like a subject, then so does Hubert", which has the form of a [donkey sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donkey_sentence#Discourse_representation_theory) and would lead to an interpretation of *a* as *every*, but I think such a reading is hardly available or at least not intended here.)

---

(d): You only need the `∀x` after `¬Like(Rut, Rut)`:

```
  ¬Like(Rut, Rut) ∧ ∀x(Like(x, Rut) -> Like(Rut, x))
```

But it doesn't hurt to move the quantifier to the front, the formulas are logically equivalent.

---

(e): As in (c), your ∀ should be a ∃:

```
  ∃x∃y (Subject(y) ∧ y = math ∧ Like(x, y) ∧  Like(Gustav, x))
```

---

(f): Ruth likes logic, not math (probably just a typo).  As in the English sentence, simply use "and" to make your four senteces into one:

```
∀x (Subject(x) ∧ x ≠ math ∧ x ≠ logic -> Like(Hubert, x))
∧ ∀x (Subject(x) ∧ x = math -> Like(Gustav, x))
∧ ∀x (Subject(x) ∧ x = logic -> Like(Rut, x))
∧ ∀x ((Subject(x) ∧ x = statistic) V (x = Rut) -> Like(Svante, x))
```

---

And just a minor thing about notation: It's better to keep writing conventions for non-logical symbols consistent, which includes capitalization, so if you use lowercase for constant names when takling about subjects (like `math`), then you should consider doing so as well for constant names when talking about people (like `svante`), or the other way round (writing all constant names uppercase).

Comment: Thank you for the corrections! I believe that now I understand better when to use ∃ symbol. Usage of non-logical symbols also noted. I'll keep it in mind.